# Controlling the setting of indexes of attributes with __setattr__ in classes

Tags: python, python-3.x

If I have:

```
class myclass():
    def __init__(self, x, list):
        self.x = x
        self.list = list

    def __setattr__(self, name, value):
        self.__dict__[name] = value
        #some stuff
```

and you do

```
instance = myclass(3, ['a', 'b'])
instance.x = 5
instance.list[1] = 'c'
```

The __setattr __ method will be called for the first one but not the second as only an index of an attribute is being set instead of an attribute

Is there any way to control what happens when an index of an attribute list is changed or is it just bad practice to have a list as an attribute in this way?

Comment: Side note: using `list` as a name is bad practice.

Comment: probably a bad idea calling the variable list, what is your ultimate goal? Also you don't create classes using def

Comment: Well ... It's an instance attribute, so there is no real reason why it can't be used as a name (other than your editor's syntax highlighter might get confused ...)

Comment: You can't accomplish this using a vanilla list, you'd need to create a subclass of `collections.MutableSequence` and do the handling there...

Comment: list was only used as an example.

Comment: Once it has resolve `instance.list -> some_value` there is no longer any control over what `some_value[i]` will do in `myclass`. That will be controlled by whatever class `some_value` has

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example that might do what you want:

```
import re

def c_set_port_state(portn,ports,values):
    print(portn,ports,values)

class Out:
    def __init__(self, obj):
        self.obj = obj
    def __getitem__(self, i):
        return self.obj._out[i]
    def __setitem__(self, i, value):
        self.obj._out[i] = value
        self.obj.set_out({i:value})

class In:
    def __init__(self, obj):
        self.obj = obj
    def __getitem__(self, i):
        return self.obj.get_in(i)

def _outidx0(key):
    idx = re.match(r'Out(\d)',key).group(1)
    idx0 = int(idx)-1
    return idx0

class _port_descriptor:
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
        self.idx0 = _outidx0(name)
    def __get__(self, obj, objtype):
        return obj.Out[self.idx0]
    def __set__(self, obj, value):
        obj.Out[self.idx0] = value

class Ports:
    """
    This is an example for dynamic attibutes 
    - that figure in dir() and
    - that IPython can auto-complete

    >>> ports = Ports()
    >>> ports.Out3=0
    1 dict_keys([2]) dict_values([0])
    >>> ports.Out4=1
    1 dict_keys([3]) dict_values([1])
    >>> dir(ports) # doctest: +ELLIPSIS
    ['In', 'Out', 'Out1', 'Out2', 'Out3', 'Out4', 'Out5', 'Out6', 'Out7', 'Out8', ...
    >>> ports.set_out(Out7=3) # doctest: +ELLIPSIS
    Traceback (most recent call last):
     ...
    ValueError: Output ...
    >>> ports.Out7=3 # doctest: +ELLIPSIS
    Traceback (most recent call last):
     ...
    ValueError: Output ...
    >>> ports.set_out(Out7=0)
    1 dict_keys([6]) dict_values([0])
    >>> ports.set_out({0:0,1:0,2:1})
    3 dict_keys([0, 1, 2]) dict_values([0, 0, 1])
    >>> ports.Out[2]
    1
    >>> ports.Out[2] = 0
    1 dict_keys([2]) dict_values([0])
    >>> ports.In[1]
    0

    """
    def __init__(self):
        self._out = dict((i,0) for i in range(8))
        self.Out = Out(self)
        self.In = In(self)
        for i in range(8):
            name = 'Out'+str(i+1)
            pd = _port_descriptor(name)
            setattr(self.__class__,name,pd)
    def set_out(self, out=None, **kwargs):
        if out:
            self._out.update(out)
        if kwargs:
            out = {_outidx0(k):v for k,v in kwargs.items()}
        if not out:
            out = self._out
        if any((value not in [0,1]) for value in out.values()):
            raise ValueError('Output values can only be 0 or 1, but you provided ' + str(out))
        c_set_port_state(len(out),out.keys(),out.values())
    def get_in(self, i):
        return 0 #would call an according c function, too
```